# Multiprocessing slowdowns my web-crawler?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, web-crawler

I want to download 20 csv files with the size of all of them together - `5MB`.
Here is the first version of my code:

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import datetime

def get_page(url):
    try:
        return urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    except:
        print("[warn] %s" % (url))
        raise

def get_all_links(page):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    links = []
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        url = link.get('href')
        if '.csv' in url:
            return url
    print("[warn] Can't find a link with CSV file!")

def get_csv_file(company):
    link = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=AAPL+Historical+Prices'
    g = link.find('s=')
    name = link[g + 2:g + 6]
    link = link.replace(name, company)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(get_all_links(get_page(link)), os.path.join('prices', company + '.csv'))
    print("[info][" + company + "] Download is complete!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    security_list = ["AAPL", "ADBE", "AMD", "AMZN", "CRM", "EXPE", "FB", "GOOG", "GRPN", "INTC", "LNKD", "MCD", "MSFT", "NFLX", "NVDA", "NVTL", "ORCL", "SBUX", "STX"]
    for security in security_list:
        get_csv_file(security)

    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print('[success] Total time: ' + str(end-start))
```

This code downloads 20 csv files with the size of all of them together - `5MB`, within 1.2 minute.
Then i have tried to use `multiprocessing` to make it download faster.
Here is version 2:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import multiprocessing
    start = datetime.datetime.now()

    security_list = ["AAPL", "ADBE", "AMD", "AMZN", "CRM", "EXPE", "FB", "GOOG", "GRPN", "INTC", "LNKD", "MCD", "MSFT", "NFLX", "NVDA", "NVTL", "ORCL", "SBUX", "STX"]
    for i in range(20):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=hP.get_csv_files([index] + security_list), args=(i,))
        p.start()

    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print('[success] Total time: ' + str(end-start))
```

But, unfortunately version 2 downloads 20 csv files with the size of all of them together - `5MB`, within 2.4 minutes.

**Why `multiprocessing` slowdowns my program?

What am I doing wrong?

What is the best way to download these files faster than now?**

Thank you?

Comment: First, you are not getting much speedup because downloading data is more of an IO intensive task which can be easily handled by a single process/thread. Second, creating processes is expensive. A better way would be to create a process pool (just like a thread pool) and keep dispatching it tasks as and when they come.

Comment: Creating processes is much more expensive on Windows than *ix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you are trying to start with Process in your example (I think you have a few typos). I think you want something like this:

```
processs = []
for security in security_list:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_csv_file, args=(security,))
    p.start()
    processs.append(p)

for p in processs:
    p.join()
```

You can iterate in this way over the security, create a new process for each security name and put the process in a list.

After you started all the processes, you loop over them and wait for them to finish, using join.

There is also a simpler way to do this, using Pool and its parallel map implementation.

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5)
pool.map(get_csv_file, security_list)
```

You create a Pool of processes (if you omit the argument, it will create a number equal to your processor count), and then you apply your function to each element in the list using map. The pool will take care of the rest.

Comment: With pool: TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JpBFWgxp 
I tested this version on my computer and it works. What Python version do you use?
And can you give the full traceback?

Comment: i'm using python 3, that was a fake error, here is a new error:  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\****\Documents\*****\*****\******.py", line 134, in <module>
    pool.map(hP.get_csv_files([index]+security_list), [index]+security_list)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 228, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 564, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

Comment: Don't call the function when you pass it to map, use just the name of the function (get_csv_file, without (...) ).

Also, you seem to be using a different function, which takes as arguments all the securities at the same time. That's not how you use map. The function given to map should take only one item of computation, and map will apply that function to all the items that need to be processed.